# display:block;同士横並びにしたい

Tags: css

以下のようなコードでtd1とtd2の両方にdisplay:blockを適用すると、td1の下にtd2が配置されてしまいます。
td1の右横にtd2を配置したいのですがどうしたらよいですか？
現状では、画像の黒色の配置になっていますが、td2を赤色のところに配置したいです。

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class = "td1">aaaa</td>
<td class = "td1">aaaa</td>
<td class = "td2">bbbb</td>
<td class = "td2">bbbb</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```
td.td1{display:block;}
td.td2{display:block;}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: td1の右横にtd2を配置したい、とありますが、現状では各要素の具体的な配置が不明なため、どのように配置したいのかをもう少し詳しく、図示するなどして教えていただけませんか？

Comment: 図を追加しました。図の赤色のところへtd2を配置したいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.td1`, `.td2` クラスが付与された要素の内容によっては `tr` 要素で分けますが、現状の HTML 構造であれば、 CSS Grid Layout の [`grid-template-rows` プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows)を用いて次のように実現出来ます。

```css
tr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1">aaa1</td>
    <td class="td1">aaa2</td>

    <td class="td2">bbb1</td>
    <td class="td2">bbb2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```